# The command substitution results in $((2+3)). Why doesn't it continue to expand?

Tags: bash

```
# generateArithmeticExpand   
generateArithmeticExpand() {  
 echo '$((2+3))'  
}  
  
echo $(generateArithmeticExpand)  
# => $((2+3))  
  
for i in $(generateArithmeticExpand)  
do    
 echo $i  
done  
  
# => $((2+3))
```

In the order of expansion, 'arithmetic expand' is performed after 'command substitution'. Why doesn't 'arithmetic expand' execute?

If the command substitution here results in a ‘*’, it will continue with the ‘filename expand’ step.

Comment: maybe `echo '$((2+3))'`   -> `echo $((2+3))`

Comment: Do you know what single quotes do in shell?

Comment: The relevant paragraph from the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) is: "The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and filename expansion."  Arithmetic expansion and command substitution are done at the same time, during a single left-to-right pass.  The expansions are not done recursively.  Filename expansion is done on the next pass.

Comment: If you want the shell to evaluate the contents of `$i` then you need to tell it to do so with `eval echo "$i"` but then read about the [`eval` command and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: @Shawn yes, remove the special meaning of a character and keep its literal meaning. I want to explore the expansion process of bash, so I write this code.

Comment: @pjh, thanks for your comment that points out my misunderstanding about the expansion order.  I think the final reason is that the result (`$((3+5))`) of the arithmetic expansion is not subject to lexical analysis, so the `$((` is not marked as the sign of arithmetic expansion. In filename expansion, Bash scans each word for the characters‘*’, ‘?’, and ‘[’.